# Gitlab Push to Sub Directory in Dev Branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am trying to move from github to gitlab and have created the account. I have two branches - master and development and another folder, test under development. Now, I want to commit all the changes to this test folder.

How do I do this?

I have tried `git push -u origin development/test` but does not work. Any tips?
Thanks.

Commands used:
[image]
[image]
[image: push to AndroidCoach directory]

Comment: Is that folder in a revision already? If it's part of a revision, then you can push _the revision/branch_.... but wanting to push a directory from a branch with git? That's not going to hold water

Comment: What do you mean by revision?

Comment: Git works on "revisions" (what is created when you run `git commit`).. and branches are just pointers to revisions. In order for you to be able to push "something", it has to be committed. If it's floating around in your working tree without being committed, you won't be able to push it anywhere.... and then, if it's committed, you just can't tell git to push a part of the tree of a revision (say, like only one directory). You have to push the revision object itself.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have commited to local repo but now want to push to that branch. How do I do it?

Comment: Use the same command you were using... remove the directory part and only provide the remote and the branch. That should be good enough: `git push origin development`

Comment: The command fails with "message failed to push some refs to origin" and another one - "error: src refspec development does not match any."

Comment: Also the commit has failed now it shows - '$ git commit -m "Add all files"
On branch test
nothing to commit, working tree clean ' what do I do now?

Comment: Ok..... from the _last_ commit error message I see that you are using a branch called "test"? You should probably try to push it. Also, you might want to add the commands and their outputs to the original question.

Comment: Yes, I have checked out that branch and it showed "switched to branch test" however when I try to commit or push then the errors occur

Comment: Need to see the commands and the outputs (even from the first command you tried). Otherwise, it's just guessing.

Comment: Well.... there it says that there's no local _development_ branch set up. So trying to push it, will fail. Then you created branch AndroidCoach from master (and checked it out). Do you want to push it? `git push origin AndroidCoach`.

Comment: Check again. If I use sourcetree to do this will it work

Comment: That doesn't work, will update the question to reflect error msg

Comment: Perhaps it will be simpler for you to match your vision of what you want to do to get it done.... but from the technical point of view, there will be no difference. Sourcetree can't force git to do something it can't do (like, pushing only a directory of a revision, for example).

Comment: Ok.... so you don't have a remote called _origin_ on your repo. What repos do you have set up? run `git remote show` to list them

Comment: Ok, here's what I want to do - I have clone this url  to a new folder - 
https://gitlab.com/copycon_project/sportsapp.git and save all my project files in a different directory under dev branch.

Comment: The command returns nothing, just escape sequence and $

Comment: So there's no remote set up on that repository that you are working with (so no wonder trying to push will never work). Covering material from your other comment: when you clone a repo, you will get a remote called _origin_ that points to the url that you cloned from.... but you can add one (or more) remote to any repo at any time (and call it whatever you want, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone --mirror git@firstplace.TLD/account/repo.git
cd repo.git
git push --mirror git@secondplace.TLD/account/repo.git
```

You want to mirror the repo

Comment: Should I delete the local .git file and start afresh with cloning?

Comment: Na just clone it with mirror then CD into it and push it to the new place

Comment: What does first and secondplace mean?

Comment: Its the repo URL.

Comment: So the first place will be the git URL of your repo on gitlab and the second one will be the git URL of your github. Past them and I'll update NY comment

Comment: What is the repo URLs the gitlab one and the github one